# Cобытие MouseDown не изменяет выбранный элемент ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Фрагмент кода:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.DoDragDrop(listBox1.SelectedItem, DragDropEffects.Move);
}
```

Но при этом `SelectedItem` всегда равен 1. Фокус не переключается мышкой только с клавиатуры. Как сделать, чтобы можно было выбирать строки мышкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы просто изменить значение элемента, думаю что Вам необходимо изменить значение [DragDropEffects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.dragdropeffects(v=vs.110).aspx) с `Move` на `Copy`.

- `Copy` - Данные из источника перетаскивания копируются в целевой объект.
- `Move` - Данные из источника перетаскивания перемещаются в целевой объект.

А еще не помешала бы проверка, нажали ли мы вниз и есть ли куда двигаться, а также получить индекс элемента мыши, что-то на подобии этого:

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
  int indexOfItem = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(e.X, e.Y);
  if(indexOfItem >= 0 && indexOfItem < listBox1.Items.Count)
  {
    listBox1.DoDragDrop(listBox1.Items[indexOfItem], DragDropEffects.Copy);
  }
}
```

---

Ссылка на источник MSDN для изучения: [Control.DoDragDrop - метод](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.control.dodragdrop(v=vs.110).aspx)